# Is there a sequence $(f_n)\in\ L^2([0,1])$, s.t. $\lVert f_n\rVert_2=1$, $\forall n$, but it has no convergent subsequences in $L^2([0,1])$ ?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

> Is there a sequence $(f_n)\in\ L^2([0,1])$, s.t. $\lVert f_n\rVert_2=1$, $\forall n$, but it has no convergent subsequences in $L^2([0,1])$ ?

We know at least $(f_n)$, is not convergent in the normal sense$ (because\  L^2convergence\Rightarrow a.e.convergence)
$

Is it a ''famous'' function, or can we construct it (I think we must sin, cos or characteristic function bring into play) ?

Comment: There are so many ways to do this, including the suggestions you make.  Think of a sequence of functions $f_n \in L^2$ with $\|f\| = 1$ and $\langle f_n,f_m\rangle = 0$ if $m \ne n$.

Comment: Is $\langle ,\rangle$ the inner product on $L^2$ (with integral) ?

Comment: Try to take (normalized) characteritisc of sets of the form $[1/(n+1),1/n)$, $n=1,2,\ldots$

Comment: @derivative Yes it is

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith this comment worth of an answer

Comment: @Norbert Did you take your pseudonym from Norbert Weiner?  He was born in the town I currently live in - Columbia, Missouri.  His father was a professor of languages at the University of Missouri.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith, I was asked this question several times :) This is my real name.

Answer (score 2):

Any sequence of  mutually orthogonal functions of unit norm has this property, because $\|f_m-f_n\| = \sqrt{2}$ for all $m\ne n$. For example, $f_n(t)=\exp(2\pi i n t)$.